# Regex of this <a href=\"-----------------\"> iPhone NSString

Tags: iphone, regex, xcode, nsstring

I want to use regex for the following expression.

here mail id can be any thing. but I just want to cut this string.

I was trying following code.

```
NSString *email=@"<a href=\"mailto:jimbosek@aol.com\">";
    NSString *strEmailMatchstring= @"\\b([a-zA-Z0-9%_.+\\-]+)@([a-zA-Z0-9.\\-]+?\\.[a-zA-Z]{2,6})\\b";
    if(![email isMatchedByRegex:strEmailMatchstring]){
        av=[[[UIAlertView alloc] initWithTitle:@"Message" message:@"Invalid Email-ID." delegate:self cancelButtonTitle:@"OK" otherButtonTitles:nil] autorelease]; [av show]; return NO;
    }
```

I know it is wrong. I have placed the regex of checking mail id.
I just want to 
But I don't know about regex.

What should be the correct way?

Thanks in advance for sharing your knowledge.

Answer (score 1):

Here is an RFC 2822 Compatible Regex

```
[a-z0-9!#$%&'*+/=?^_`{|}~-]+(?:\.[a-z0-9!#$%&'*+/=?^_`{|}~-]+)*@(?:[a-z0-9](?:[a-z0-9-]*[a-z0-9])?\.)+[a-z0-9](?:[a-z0-9-]*[a-z0-9])?
```

Or use this one

```
\b[A-Z0-9._%-]+@[A-Z0-9.-]+\.[A-Z]{2,4}\b
```

Answer (score 1):

Yeh. I did it.

```
NSString *strRegex=@"<a href=\"mailto:\\b([a-zA-Z0-9%_.+\\-]+)@([a-zA-Z0-9.\\-]+?\\.[a-zA-Z]{2,6})\\b\">";
            NSString *tmmpStr=[[[tmpStr stringByReplacingOccurrencesOfString:@" valign=\"top\"" withString:@""] stringByReplacingOccurrencesOfString:@"<b>" withString:@""] stringByReplacingOccurrencesOfString:@"</b>" withString:@""];
            NSString *tmp2=[tmmpStr stringByReplacingOccurrencesOfRegex:strRegex withString:@""];
            NSString *tmp3=[tmp2 stringByReplacingOccurrencesOfString:@"</a>" withString:@""];
            NSLog(@"%@",tmp3);
```

Comment: @Kendall Yes, you can - after 48 hours. http://blog.stackoverflow.com/2009/01/accept-your-own-answers/